# "Бешеные бабки"

Tags: сленг

Откуда пошел обычай на жаргоне называть деньги "бабками"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обсуждалось неоднократно и продолжает обсуждаться. Даю, что помню.
Достоверно известно, что слово получило широкое распространение на ранее 70-х г. XX века. 
В фильме "Офицеры" главный герой (Юматова) жалуется, что ему трудно будет поднять сына, поскольку у них "бабок нет". Сейчас воспринимается как "нет денег". Но там - в прямом значении. Вряд ли бы авторы допустили подобную двусмысленность, существуй она в те годы (середина 60-х). На этот эпизод многие бабковеды обращали внимание, ваш покорный - в том числе.

1. Бабки - снопы. Идеальная, казалось бы, версия, на бабки-снопы действительно считали урожай - и его цену. Но одно "маленькое но". Значение современное, давно уже все про эти снопы забыли.
2. От бабка - чаcть ноги лошади над копытом, сустав. Эта костяшка использовалась в огромном числе всячесих игр (включая и ту, что похожа на городки) и высоко ценилась. То же возражение, хотя и не столь категоричное, поскольку все, что связано с играми, особенно азартными, могло сохраниться независимо от происхождния.
3. От "боб" - на "бобы" вроде бы считали прибыль. Видимо, исходно "боб" - костяшка для счет.
4. Заимствование из тюркских или иранских, называются разные источники и разные значения. Всё - недостоверно.
   В инете еще есть версии, соверешенно фантастические, опускаю.
   Про Березовского - шутка, понятно.

Answer (score 4):

Уследить этимологию жаргонных слов очень тяжело. Покопавшись в интернете, я нашёл кучу вариантов, например:

```
Одна из версий - бабками в старину
называли сложенные снопы в поле. У
кого больше бабок, тот и богаче.
Вторая версия - дворовая игра в
"бабки" - типа городков, палкой
сбивали сложенные косточки. Кто сбил,
тот себе их и забирает.
```

[Пруф.](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/92469-otkuda-pojavilos-slovo-bablo.html)

или

```
Согласно изысканиям М.Фасмера,
древнеславянское слово «бабъло»
восходит к инициалам Б. А.
Березовского, известного лондонского
эмигранта и коллекционера дензнаков.
Версии о происхождении слова от
названия станции «Вавилон-5»
(«Babylon-5») и от ритуального выкрика
«Кинь бабе лом» (восходящего к В.
И.Ленину) принято считать
малодоказательными.
```

[Пруф на абсурдопедию (недостоверный источник).](http://absurdopedia.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Второй источник ссылается на Фасмера, но я не нашёл никаких доказательств, что в его словаре есть такое слово.
Так что выбирайте сами, чему верить, а чему нет. В этимологии жаргонов всё всегда очень мутно.

Comment: @МаркИз Мне кажется, что последнюю правку надо откатить - текст стал нечитабельным.